# Ruby on Rails: Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, devise

I am having trouble deleting and showing user records.

Here is my routes.rb

```
FinalApp::Application.routes.draw do


resources :users
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'admin' }



    resources :projects
    match "search" => "projects#search", :as => :search

    root :to => 'projects#index'
end
```

Here is my admin controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
def index
    @users = User.all



respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @users }
    end
  end

def create

    @user = User.new(params[:user])



    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end




  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
@user_user_id = params[:id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json



  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my view:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin" %>
<body>
<div id ="title1">Admin</div>

<div class ="menu"></div>
<div id ="section3">
<table id = "mytable">
<table border = "1">
 <tr>
    <th>Username </th>


    <th>Email</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
<th>Admin?</th>

    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>

  </tr>
  <%= link_to "New User", admin_new_path  %><br />

<% @users.each do |t| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= t.username %></td>

    <td><%= t.email %></td>
    <td><%= t.firstname %></td>

    <td><%= t.lastname %></td>
<td><%= t.admin %></td>


    <td><%= link_to 'Show', t %></td>
    <td> <%= button_to "Delete", t, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table></br>

</body>

</html>
```

I can display the User database, but when I go to delete a record. I get this error `No route matches [DELETE] "/users/11"`. I am new to rails so please remember this when trying to help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: here are my routes =>

```
    admin_index GET    /admin(.:format)               admin#index
                         POST   /admin(.:format)               admin#create
               new_admin GET    /admin/new(.:format)           admin#new
              edit_admin GET    /admin/:id/edit(.:format)      admin#edit
                   admin GET    /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#show
                         PUT    /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#update
                         DELETE /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        admin#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               admin#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       admin#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          admin#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               admin#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               admin#destroy
                projects GET    /projects(.:format)            projects#index
                         POST   /projects(.:format)            projects#create
             new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)        projects#new
            edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)   projects#edit
                 project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#show
                         PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#update
                         DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#destroy
                  search        /search(.:format)              projects#search
                    root        /                              projects#index
```

EDIT2: This is how my routes.rb file should have looked. Using rake routes I was able to change the paths to fix my problem.

```
FinalApp::Application.routes.draw do

  # website home
  root :to => 'projects#index'

  # devise sessions (NB does not use admin/users controller)
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users' }

  # normal controllers
  resources :users
  resources :projects

  # custom routes
  match "search" => "projects#search", :as => :search

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ended up with two routes leading to admin#destroy:

```
DELETE /users(.:format)               admin#destroy
DELETE /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#destroy
```

and yet you have no route which matches /users/xx, just a route which matches DELETE /users with an optional format bit. You have a route which matches /admin/11 so if you tried that it would work, however I would try to simplify things a bit.

Do you actually need to specify a controller on the devise resources? What exactly do you want to override there, as you have ended up with a load of routes (like cancel) which lead nowhere and some which clash...

Try a simpler routes definition (NB this requires renaming your AdminController UsersController instead, I would follow this convention as it will make your life easier, and match your other urls, so you end up with users/1 etc, not admin/1)

```
FinalApp::Application.routes.draw do

  # website home
  root :to => 'projects#index'

  # devise sessions (NB does not use admin/users controller)
  devise_for :users

  # normal controllers
  resources :users
  resources :projects

  # custom routes
  match "search" => "projects#search", :as => :search

end
```

Then do rake routes to make sure you understand where the routes are pointing. You need a route which says (NB the :id bit):

```
DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
```

or if you prefer an admin controller (and are willing to sort out the custom routes)

```
DELETE /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#destroy
```

Perhaps before diving into this though you could read through the rails routing guide as it might clear a few things up for you:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I am wanting the users to be able to login, and if they have been given admin status, they can get to a admin part of the website, where new users can be created, edited and deleted. I will give you suggestions a go. Thanks.

Comment: While it is possible to try namespacing certain actions/controllers, I would recommend that rather than namespace a few user actions under /admin, you simply add redundant checks for certain actions to be sure that only those users can perform important actions. As your app grows you will need multiple restrictions due to user status (admin,reader, other?). Look into cancan for this, or set up your own simpler roles system.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `resources :users` to your `routes.rb`. In any case, you can always check `rake routes` in your console to see the available routes.

On a side note, the way you define you `admin` routes are not completely correct. Not everything is a `get`. For example, creating an `admin` would be a `post`. The easiest way is just to use something like `resources :admins`.

Comment: I have added my routes for you to see. Adding `resources :users` just seems to add loads more routes, and doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You might need to add it outside the `devise_for` block.

Comment: I have moved the resources :users above the devise_for block

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a pretty standard use of Devise with your only notable difference being the name of your Controller.  Therefore, the only thing you should need for devise routing is:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'admin' }
```

Also, delete all of your "get 'admin/*'" entries.  Not every HTTP method is a GET when you're working in a REST environment. [Here is one article that discusses REST methods.](http://bradley-holt.com/2009/07/html-5-http-methods-rest/)

Comment: I have updated my question after your suggestions. Still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: You should not need to manually expose the :users resource because you're already using Devise.  Devise takes care of all your route generating.  So, your entire routes file should only have one line for devise, one line for your root path, one line for your projects resource, and one line for your 'search' route matching.